# browser's "Save password": how to tell what's username and what's password?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, browser, registration

When user register on my page and click "Save password", chrome will fill into login form right password but instead of email chrome fills phone number.

How to prevent it?

Comment: Please show the form code for that.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding browser fills the info based on the name of the input box. Do you have a link we can test?

Comment: thank's for answer, here is link: http://eshop.dttrading.sk/textil, or google translated http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Feshop.dttrading.sk%2Ftextil